# Acid/Base Indicator

Tags: acid-base, ph

I'm not sure how the concept and math work on this problem. Can someone show me how you can get the answer, both conceptually and using math?

[image: Indicators and their pH ranges]

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the question this way: when we have a strong acid/strong base titration, at the equivalence point we would end up with a neutral solution (the $\mathrm{pH}$ would be ~$7$).

If we had a weak acid/strong base titration, at the equivalence point we would end up with $\mathrm{pH}$ above 7 (basic solution has $\mathrm{pH}$ between $8-10$).

If we had a weak base/strong acid titration, we would end up with an acidic solution with $\mathrm{pH}$ $4-6$)

Coming back to your question: since it is asked about the methyl red indicator, we are going to need something which at the equivalent point would have acidic solution which means you need weak base/strong acid combinations,only option (C) fulfils this.